# Can't remove today view extension from iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I tried to remove an iOS8 today view extension from my iOS App in Xcode6, but somehow the extension is still built and always appearing on the device. I removed both the extensions files from the project as well as the build target. I also removed the application multiple times but the widget is still always copied whenever I build the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a solution: in the menu go to `Product` > `Clean` and the extensions that are not used or built anymore are gone!

Answer (score 16):

If you want to keep the sourcecode and only remove the today widget:

- go to your app target into your project file
- select General -> Embedded binaries
- remove the TodayWidgetName.appex file with the minus button
- do a clean

If you compile or archive you should not see any longer the today widget appearing in the iOS notification center.

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different, but important question:  If you want to delete an extension from a Target in Xcode, how would you do so?  You are correct that this retains all your source files, and will remove the extension from the build process for that Target.

Comment: This might be useful if you have to disable today widget temporarily from the app store release for some reason e.g. until it is tested or approved by the management etc; but obviously you don't want to remove your code.

Comment: YEA, I knew that it's possible to keep the source code

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a way of removing embedded binaries from compiled IPA package if you don't want to recompile. Obviously, after altering the package you'll have to resign it.

This is where embedded binaries are placed:
Payload > .app > PlugIns > .appex

I've tried removing the PlugIns and resigning the whole bundle - seems to be working well.